# Application or web service to alert me whenever one of my StackExchange questions is put on hold / gets on closed

Tags: stack-exchange

Quite often some of my StackExchange questions is put on hold / gets on closed, unbeknownst to me.

I'm looking for an application, browser extension or userscript to scan my questions and alert me whenever one of my StackExchange question is put on hold / gets on closed (since StackExchange don't notify users despite [heavy public demand in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/178179)).

Ideally, in case the question gets deleted it would save the content somewhere (since [StackExchange don't notify users about the deletion, and don't send the removed content by email](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209694/178179)).

And if possible:

- works on Windows 7 + Google Chrome
- free

Comment: I guess there is no RSS feed for this?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul not that i'm aware of.

Comment: AFAIK closed questions does not have RSS feed, so add the question to an RSS reader which notifies you later when the RSS feed is unavailable.

Comment: Perhaps this should be in SE meta.  By default I would think it would be wise to both notify users when something is on hold, and also to require a comment from the holder as to why.  (The canned explanations suck.)

Answer (score 5):

### [SE Closed Questions Notifier](http://shu8.github.io/SE-Closed-Questions-Notifier/) on Github

I've made a web-app to do (kind of) what you want.

It works assuming one thing: You check the web-app *regularly* (ie. once a week/month).

Every time you visit the app, it saves the current date and time (to localStorage). Next time you check, it will look at the date saved last time and check if any sites you've chosen to check have had questions closed since the last time you checked.

There are 2 sections:

- all closed questions
- questions that have closed since you last checked

[image]

You can choose the site you want to check via the button at the top.

---

Note: This **does not** save any data about the questions. All it saves is the last time you checked, so, to get the most reliable results, you need **to check the site regularly**. I *might* turn this into a userscript that automatically adds a notification if users ask for it.

Comment: How hard would it be to extend this script into checking for reopened questions as well? Maybe storing locally the question number of closed question, and then on the next check see if any of those are missing  from the current closed question list?

Comment: @holroy yeah - that would be how it would be done. In terms of *extending* this script, it may take more effort than to just create a new script altogether! Would you be interested in something like that? No promises though...!

Comment: @holroy BTW you might be interested in my userscript version of this web app at Stack Apps: [Question Close Notifier - a userscript to notify you when one of your questions close somewhere on the network](http://stackapps.com/q/6384/26088) :)

Comment: ^^that also is something that could be rewitten to include reopened questions as well...

Comment: Not me, but Frank Dernoncourty is/was in [this question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4374/14982). (I was just reading through some old unanswered question when I found it on Software Recommendations)

Comment: hmmm I see... I might have a go, shouldn't be too hard...! But I guess it's *less* (although still) important when a question is *reopened* - because it generally means you don't need to do anymore! just wait for answers/comments... but yeah - I might have a go! :)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to set up a filter with email notifications on the Stack Exchange "My filters" page that notifies you by email every 15 minutes of all the new questions to have the `closed-questions` tag.

Then set up a rule in your email client, (most have a way of doing so), that deletes the message if your name is **not** in the message body and another to notify you if it does. *(Details vary with different email clients).*

You then have your notifications without running any software that you are not running already, (so no additional cost), *close enough to free* and this solution should work on just about any operating system.