# Alert when an SE question gets reopened

Tags: stack-exchange

I am looking for some user script or web service to receive an alert when a question on StackExchange is reopened. I should be able to bookmark which closed question I am interested in. There is [no built-in feature in SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230959/178179) allowing such notification as some don't see the point in it.

Comment: Isn't this a similar thing? http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2887/1925

Comment: Same kind, but in this case I want to be notified when the question is reopened, not closed.

Comment: A good effort, which can be made better: there already exists more appropriate place for asking this question: [Stackapps SE site](http://stackapps.com/) / tag [app-request](http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app-request) which is given to *Questions about whether [app]s with certain functionality exist. Some members of the community may react to these questions by creating those [app]s, should they not exist.*

Comment: @miroxlav A question can be on-topic on two sites without any problem. This might fit on Stack Apps also, but it's on topic here as well. It's the author's choice.

Comment: @Undo – thanks for pointing at that. So now the only remaining point is that the same question asked on the other site could be answered there more quickly and appropriately. Maybe the author will still create the same question on Stackapps, linking both questions together – let's see.

Comment: Would a local solution work? i.e. a script that fetches the contents of a list of linked webpages and searches for the ``[closed]`` or ``[on hold]`` keywords.

Comment: @Timmy Yes local solution works too. That shouldn't be too hard to code, but I wonder whether some ready-to-use solutions already exist.

Comment: Along the lines of @Timmy's question: how about a browser add-on that you can use to detect changes in web pages, such as [PageMonitor](http://max99x.com/chrome-extensions/page-monitor) for Chrome, or [Update Scanner](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/update-scanner/) for Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

[IFTTT (If This Then That)](https://ifttt.com/) is a website that lets you connect services and websites together. Each StackExchange post has an RSS feed. Use that as an input to your recipe. You'd have to have separate instances for each page you want to follow, but it would work. Your output could be an e-mail.

Comment: I don't see anything in the RSS feed that could I do care a reopened question clearly enough to be useful for this requirement.

Comment: When it is closed, no changes can be made. When it's re-opened, the `updated` tag will change, notifying you. It's not about what is in the RSS. You just need a notification telling you it's been re-opened.

Comment: he could probably also use http://data.stackexchange.com/ to create query and then write some app to launch it (via http) and process it. The only thing is that the data there are 20 hours old.